# R: can't fit an mlogit() model, singularity error

Tags: r, model-fitting, mlogit

I am fitting a *Multinomial Logit model* to choice data. When I have introduced a variable *gender*, suddenly, I can no longer fit a model as I am presented with an error message:

```
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[8,8] = 0
```

Here's my dataset:

[image: Choice dataset]

```
attributes <- expand.grid(
  company = c("Metalac", "NikolaTeslaAirport", "Jedinstvo", "Energoprojekt"),
  return_rate = c(0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15),
  dividend = c(0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6),
  trend = c("Trend1", "Trend2", "Trend3")
)

set.seed(123)

gen <- sample(c("male", "female"), size = 100, prob = c(0.3669, 0.6331), replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:100, each = 3), 
  alternative = as.factor(rep(1:3, times = 100)), 
  choice = 0, 
  gender = rep(gen, each = 3),
  attributes[sample(nrow(attributes), size = 100 * 3, replace = TRUE), ]
)

df <- df %>% mutate(
  gender = as.factor(gender),
  company = as.factor(company),
  return_rate = as.numeric(return_rate),
  dividend = as.numeric(dividend),
  trend = as.factor(trend)
)
```

The model that I'm trying to fit:

```
fit2 <- mlogit(choice ~ company + return_rate + dividend + gender, data = df)
```

I actually have no clue on what to do, unfortunately.